# How to compile Android library?

Tags: java, android, compilation, aar

In my project I am using [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

Due to a feature that I needed, I cloned the project to my machine and manipulated the library. I tested my feature on its demo project and everything is okay based on this project.

Now, I want to compile its `library` module in order to get `.aar` file and add it to my project. What I did is:

1. I opened cmd and navigated to root folder of `slidingUpPanel` project.
2. Ran this command: `./gradlew :library:build`
3. Library compiled and created .aar under `/library/build/outputs/aar/library-debug.aar`

I copy/pasted this file into `/libs` folder of my project and updated `build.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile ANDROID_SUPPORT
    compile CRASHLYTICS
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

    // Local libs not in Maven Central
    compile files('src/main/libs/httpclientandroidlib-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/niftynotification-1.2.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/zendesk-1.0.0.1.jar')

    compile files('src/main/libs/library-debug.aar')
}
```

After I sync gradle file, I'm getting error which is because [SlidingUpPanelLayout](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java) does not recognise.

Any idea why the library cannot be recognised? Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, first, lets add this kind of repository in our build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Here, I assume that your aar files will be stored in the libs folder in your project.

You can now add a dependency like

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'net.my.package:mylib:1.0@aar'
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reasons I cannot define `libs` directory under flatDir. Is there any inline definition? also can you tell me what is `mylib` and `1.0`? thanks